# Creating Large DataFrame from smaller DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am having an issue with the structure of data as I get it off the PGA website. I have trouble putting the data into a dataframe and merging the data so that I can use the dataframe for analysis later. The dimensions of the scraped data are never right. I get a separate error each time I run the code that I cant seem to reconcile.

I have tried merging and concatenating dataframes but nothing seems to work. ANy help is appreciated

I would really like for my dataframe to contain the individual statistics from the separate sites but on the same row as the other data formatted by the year and PLAYER NAME.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import socket
import urllib.error
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import sqlalchemy
import numpy as np
import functools

base = 'http://www.pgatour.com/'
inn = 'stats/stat'
end = '.html'
years = ['2017','2016']


alpha = []
#all pages with links to tables
urls =     ['http://www.pgatour.com/stats.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.ROTT_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RAPP_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RARG_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RPUT_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RSCR_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RSTR_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RMNY_INQ.html','http://www.pgatour.com/stats/categories.RPTS_INQ.html']
for i in urls:
    data = urlopen(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            alpha.append(base + link['href'][17:]) #may need adjusting
#data links
beta = []
for i in alpha:
    if inn in i:
        beta.append(i)

gamma = []
for i in beta:
    if i not in gamma:
        gamma.append(i)

jan = []
for i in gamma:
    try:
        data = urlopen(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        for table in soup.find_all('section',{'class':'module-statistics-off-the-tee-details'}):
            for j in table.find_all('h3'):
                y=j.get_text().replace(" ","").replace("-","").replace(":","").replace(">","").replace("<","").replace(">","").replace(")","").replace("(","").replace("=","").replace("+","")
                jan.append([i,str(y+'.csv')])
                print([i,str(y+'.csv')])
    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

#my problem starts here
#using urls list so that I can find error faster
urls = [['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html','d']
    ,['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02568.html','f']
    ,['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.111.html','r']]        
list = []
master = pd.DataFrame()
#jan = [['http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.02356.html', 'Last15EventsScoring.csv']]
#make a list with url and title name and cleaned csv name
#write to csv
row_sp = []
rows_sp =[]
title1 = [] 
title = []  
for i in urls:
    try:
        for y in years:
            data = urlopen(i[0][:-4] +y+ end)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            data1 = urlopen(i[0])
            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
            for table in soup1.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                title.append('year')
                for k in table.find_all('tr'):
                    for n in k.find_all('th'):
                        title1.append(n.get_text())
                        for l in title1:
                            if l not in title:
                                title.append(l)
                rows_sp.append(title)
            for table in soup.find_all('table',{'id':'statsTable'}):
                for h in table.find_all('tr'):
                    row_sp = [y]
                    for j in h.find_all('td'):
                        row_sp.append(j.get_text().replace(" ","").replace("\n","").replace("\xa0"," "))
                    rows_sp.append(row_sp)
            df=pd.DataFrame(rows_sp)
            df.columns = title
            df.drop(df.index[1],inplace = True)
            print(df)
            list.append(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
df_merge = functools.reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['year','PLAYER NAME'], how='outer'), list)
```